# Can it print anything in main

Tags: java, netbeans, println

Im writing a java app at the moment and nothing is being run! I can even print simple `System.out.println("hi");`

Below is the code. I can see the output window fine. No errors are being returned. Im using netbeans 8.0.2

```
public class BookingSystem{

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print("hi"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, what's the question? (ps `print` buffers until a new line character is reached)

Comment: Try println instead of print

Comment: How can i get main to work/ how can i get the print statement to print. The same statement was working last week. Didn't work with println

Comment: Nothing i put in main works (nothing is written in the output box and theres no errors)

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code and not something else?

Comment: Im definitely running it. There's nothing else open.

Comment: Can you try putting a breakpoint on the call to `System.out.print`?  This way, you can see exactly what Exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a problem in running the code you have posted. Make sure that you are running the `BookingSystem` class and not some other class. Use 'Run File' in Netbeans (or Shift+F6) to run the `BookingSystem` class.

Answer (score -3):

Try the same code in notepad, compile and run the program in command prompt.

Comment: After these downvotes to my answer, I did try writing the exact code given in the question in notepad and compiling using command prompt. And it works perfectly for both System.out.print() and System.out.println()